# SetEnvIfNoCase match part of url not working / Secure special page with an authentication

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, regex

I'm currently trying to secure a shop category in WooCommerce with a basic authentication including all products in this shop. For that I've found this code on Stackoverflow for my `.htaccess` file:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/product-category/langzeitvermietung/ SECURED
AuthName "Kundenbereich"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /
Require valid-user

Satisfy    any
Order      Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=SECURED
```

The problem is that somehow it's not matching correctly and I don't get any prompt. I have two possible urls:

1. One for the category itself: https://example.com/product-category/langzeitvermietung/
2. One for a product inside a category: https://example.com/shop/product-category/langzeitvermietung/testvermietung/

So how can I deal with this? The idea is to prevent access to a specific category and its products inside (seconds link example).

I'm using WordPress with WooCommerce so I hope the redirect rules are still getting applied below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Maybe this can be also a problem when using this kind of protection? Somehow I got it working but in this case I got redirected to my servers default page and not to the WordPress page after authenticating successfully.

Comment: Or does anyone has an idea how I can verify if the url get's correctly directed and checked?

Comment: The second URL (product _inside_ the catgeory) has an additional `/shop` prefix - is that intentional? `AuthUserFile .htpasswd` - presumably you are using the absolute filesystem path in your actual directive?